# Sprout Forms: Modify Entry

Tags: plugins, plugin-sproutforms

In the Sprout Forms plugin, is there a way to modify the EntryModel through sproutForms.onBeforeSaveEntry? I have a plugin that sends a cURL request onBeforeSaveEntry, and I'd like to grab the response from that and deliver it to the user on the thank you page.

I've tried setting new properties on the $event object but I'm getting errors, so maybe my approach is wrong? Been searching, but unable to find how to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out you can modify an existing property like this:

```
$event->params['entry']->getContent()->existingProperty = 'new value';
```

What I ended up doing was using a hidden field and then updating the value of that from the sproutForms.onBeforeSaveEntry event:

```
craft()->on('sproutForms.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    $entry->getContent()->subscribeStatus = 'success';
});
```

Since that property can be set depending on what the response is from the cURL post, it's possible to deliver success/error messages to users on the thank you page and prevent the subscribe from silently failing in the background.